# Android SharedPreferences class uses wrong annotation reference

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I updated the **build.gradle** file for an old Android project to use the the new **androidx** implementation references instead of the old compile references. Throughout the app I had to replace all my import **android.support.annotation.Nullable** with the new **androidx.annotation.Nullable** ones. This seems to work fine for the app's own custom codebase.

However, the app also has a **SharedPreferences** class that uses the **android.content.SharedPreferences** class. The latter one keeps referencing the old **android.annotation.Nullable** which gives me a *'Cannot resolve symbol'* error now. I included the following implementations in my build.gradle file, I don't know if I'm missing anything to keep this working as it should?

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.4'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```